# How to implement a customized spinner to select time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to implement a time select Widget, it should look something like this:
[Image_Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj6jJ.png).
And it should work like shown in this video:

https://streamable.com/2y7s65.

I would like to have the design, shown in the picture combined with the wheel in the video to select a specific time.

But I am struggling with this for a while. I know there is a package: flutter_time_picker_spinner, but I count't find any way to customize the spinner in the way I need to (like in the picture: [Image_Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj6jJ.png) )

I hope I gave enough information, if something is still unclear please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be download https://github.com/icemanbsi/flutter_time_picker_spinner/blob/master/lib/flutter_time_picker_spinner.dart and style it as you like.

Comment: I am currently trying it and it seems to work, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListWheelScrollView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUhmWAz4C7Y&vl=en) to get the result you are looking for.  Style each individual button the way you want and add them as children.  From there you can style the ListWheelScrollView to get your desired look.